# What is the best way to have failover connection for OpenVPN client

Tags: networking, openvpn, netplan, network-bonding, failover

I am going to make failover connection for OpenVPN client.
What will be the best way to achieve it?

I have two ethernet interfaces. I connect eth0 to LAN (with DHCP), and eth1 to GSM router (with static IP). The eth0 (LAN connection) should always be preferred. For make eth0 preferred I tried to use metrics, but then the internet doesn't work over backup interface, when primary goes down.

Is there possibility to use bonding (in active-backup mode) of eth0 and eth1 in this case?

How to configure the bonding for one dhcp interface and one static in Netplan (Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS Server)?